# composer: command not found phpstorm

Tags: phpstorm, composer

Изучаю Ларавель по урокам в сети. Пишу все в phpstorm на OpenServer. Изначально установил лару именно через компосер.

Сейчас нужно было установить пакет, но мне выдает

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Попробовал переустановил его

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не помогает.... Как его реанимировать?

Answer (score 0):

вместо composer нужно начинать команду (в консоли PHPStorm) php composer.phar  и далее что вам нужно